# Google webmaster URL crawl error - 301 moved permanently

Tags: .htaccess, google-search-console

There are many question on SO similar to mine but none has solved my issue.

I have installed SSL on a wordpress website recently prior to which everything was working fine including SEARCH RESULTS. After installing SSL my site rank dropped drastically and page views dropped to 300 from 1500 approx. This is a big shock to me.

I reset everything in my google webmaster account including sitemap.xml after which I found `fetch as google` says the following `301 Moved Permanently`

[image]

I have this in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I want the following to work

```
http:// domain.com (works)
https:// domain.com (works)
http:// subomain.domain.com (is automatically redirected to https. I don't have wildcard ssl installed and this causes error)
```

I want the domain.com to be forced to https and all subdomains to http. How do I get this done

Comment: No answer at all ??

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the website through https:// as well? If not yet, I suggest to verify the website this way as it suggested to verify your domain with all  versions. Try out this way and hopefully it will resolve your error.

Keep both (http:// and https://) versions verified, it will not harm your site in anyway.

Let me know if I can be of more help to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this thing also from your cPanel..

Steps:

1. login to your cPanel
2. go on DOMAIN Section
3. Click on redirect button in this section.
4. Then ADD REDIRECTION through that page..

whatever domain or sub domain you want to redirect..